# set border to make column using col class of bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

http://bootply.com/84064#

the border's length doesn't reach to the entire column, I can't make it to certain height because it broke when I resize it, since bootstrap is responsive..

what I want is 3 boxes that can fills the entire height..

Comment: What border? I don't understand your question. Can you please explain?

Comment: @Skelly the border as shown in the example doesn't fill up the full height of the page, I can't set the div / section to certain height because since bootstrap is responsive, it may ruined the layout if I do that..